# What are some strategies to test blocks tied to EventMachine::WebSocket events?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testing, websocket, eventmachine

I'm trying to test some code that I've written to respond to the `onopen`, `onmessage`, and `onclose` events that can be registered via [`EventMachine::WebSocket`](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-websocket), and I'm curious to know if there are any utilities that could help mock out some of the EventMachine functionality for unit tests. Links to example em-websocket tests would be greatly appreciated; I've looked all over to find example tests, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to mock the `Websocket::Connection` instance yourself? I would start by setting up a an object with a `send` method?

For example:

```
class ConnectionMock
  def send(msg)
  end
end
```

then create an instance of that to represent the typical `ws` instance used in the em-websocket documentation. The `onmessage` is the only event which passes an argument, which is a string, so there's not much need to mock much else for these events. I would start with this base object and mock more methods as needed.

Here's an example of a EM-Websocket mock from [Socky](https://github.com/socky/socky-server-ruby/blob/master/spec/spec_helper.rb).